# Disparity among users regarding question-posting ban

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, post-ban

A few days ago, I lost the privilege of asking questions on MSE, because my questions are "not well-received" according to the system. Before losing this privilege, I had asked a total of $5$ questions, with $1$ upvote in one question, and $0$ upvote in the rest $4$.

By the way, I have written $18$ answers so far on MSE with a total of $16$ upvotes. Among them, $9$ answers were accepted by the authors of those questions. Currently, I have $441$ reputation score, $3$ silver badges, and $14$ bronze badges.

---

Today, I saw an user with $25$ reputation score, and $5$ bronze badges. The user has asked $13$ questions, with $1$ upvote in two questions, and $0$ upvote in rest eleven. He/She hasn't written any answer so far.

---

My question is, how does this system work ? Undoubtedly, my contributions are much more than the user who I'm talking about. But I'm the one who is prohibited from asking questions since almost a month. Why should there be so much bias ?

**Note :** *The reason I'm making this comparison is because I think this is very unfair. I just want back the privilege of asking questions.*

Comment: If any of your former questions were deleted, by yourself, or closed and deleted by others, the outcome and quality of of those questions are also taken into account, when it comes to banning a user from asking questions.

Comment: Oh I see. I deleted $3$ of the questions at first, but later, I undeleted them. Isn't that enough now ? :(

Comment: @Kolmogorov Suspensions are removed if the system thinks your contribution was good for the community (Sole indication being upvotes/bookmarks). since you cannot ask from your account anymore [visit here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355390/). Do not abuse this as you may earn a IP ban.

Comment: Please don't recommend people try to circumvent the system. Note that **any** use of the recommendation made by Anindya Prithvi is abuse of the system, and should (depending on who handles it, will) result in a broader suspension, as well as being unlikely to remove the original question suspension.

Comment: @Nij Quality bans are localised to an account. If the account circumvents the ban but contributes a quality post, the quality ban is removed. Although abuse of this feature logs the persons IP address, this implies they do not have infinite attempts. Read the post by Shog9 linked in the answer and the measures taken by the moderation team.

Comment: Suspensions are meant to apply to the person, not the account. Shog9's answer on the Meta FAQ is clear, and is exactly as RyanM quoted: if you cannot ask questions with the primary account, creating a secondary account to ask questions is abuse of the system (this is certainly not a feature, sockpuppets are at best a technical loophole).

Comment: But to address this direct concern: the fact you've given a bunch of **answers** (assuming the best status of a net positive and median positive score) and some arbitrary other user has not, means nothing when the objects of interest are **questions**. You write poor questions, as measured by the standards that the SE system applies, and therefore you have a question suspension. The other user, who is actually irrelevant here anyway, does not and therefore does not. @Kolmogorov

Comment: `You write poor questions, as measured by the standards that the SE` this is a consequence of how the system is programmed and ofc it is not perfect. Someone who's posts are isolated may not be contacted much (therefore no up or downvotes). IN the same way they can be downvotes without a reason as well (most common thing I have come across) can push a user over the quality ban even though the questions perfectly met the community standards. There are multiple examples where this has happened. Anyways, a positive sock puppet is not a harm to SE, where's the problem in + anyways. Blatant abuse -

Comment: is punished severely by a network wide suspension. So,, in any case it's a win win unless someone has intentions of watching people suffer things they shouldnt have. @Nij

Comment: I'm not clear as to what Questions of yours have been deleted and (from what you say above) undeleted by you.  You've been a member for more than two years, but the only Questions I see on your activity page are five from the last three months.  In any case one thing you can do is improve your existing (unanswered) Questions.  You might ask in chat for suggestions on how to do this.